# Update a winforms label or textbox using database data

Tags: c#, database, data-binding

I'd like to retrieve some text from a database and use this data to update a label or textbox's value.
My only experience so far has been binding a database to a gridview, but that method does not work in this scenario.
Please can you advise?

Comment: NEVER use caps on your question title

Comment: And please provide more details about what you want

Comment: Show us what you have done. If you can bind the database to a gridview, kindly show the code. It will help

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough example.  In the real world you'd want to reuse your connection object / maybe make use of DatabaseFactories and ConnectionPooling. This example only shows a simple way to populate label text with info from the database.

```
const string ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
const string GetLabelText = "select labeltext from myLabelTextTable where id={0}";
const string DefaultLabelText = "-undefined-";

public void UpdateLabel(Label myLabel, int labelTextId)
{
    string labelText;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(string.Format(GetLabelText,labelTextId), connection))
        {
            labelText = (command.ExecuteScalar() ?? DefaultLabelText).ToString();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    myLabel.Text = labelText;
}
```

Comment: +1 just an FYI ConnectionPooling is done in SQL Server - in .Net you just reuse the same connection string and SQL does the rest. Also the `using` doesn't require the `connection.close()` but I guess you left it in to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThompson; didn't know that about connection pooling.  You're correct on using - just included as I'd expect the above to be re-factored for the real world, where the using statements may be removed because the connection isn't created and disposed in the same method.